# Gradle task to execute Grails service

Tags: hibernate, grails, gradle, service

Is it possible to create a Gradle task to execute a Grails Service method?

In my Grails application I have a service which is used to calculate data to deploy on the destination server, usually I use to invoke a Controller from the browser to generate the data, but I would prefer to do it via script in order to include only automatic commands in the deployment procedure.

Note: I cannot just instantiate the class because it needs Grails to be running in order to use the Hibernate and domain classes configuration.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is, to use the quartz plugin to start a service with a schedule:

https://grails.org/plugin/quartz

The documentation can be found here:

http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/scheduling.html

A Job to start a service would simply look like this:

```
class ImportJob {
    static triggers = {
        simple name: 'importJob', startDelay: 0, repeatInterval: 500 // execute job once in 500 milliseconds
    }

    def ighImportService

    def concurrent = false

    def execute() {
       ighImportService.processNextChunk()
    }
}
```

In this example a ighImporService is injected into the importJob and its processNextChunk() method will be loaded every 500 ms.